# C#: How to plot OHLC data

Tags: c#, wpf, plot

I am writing a little analysis tool (as a WPF application) that requires me being able to load up CSV files, eye ball an OHLC chart and posibly draw some trendlines. I'm therefore, not interested in any of the existing packages/controls out there that come with additional stuff I'm not interested in/don't need.

I have spent a lot of time searching online, but all of the examples I have come accross contain too much unneccessary stuff, as I'm looking for an absolute barebones plotting library that can plot only one type of chart (for now at least - I will add custom plotting later).

I therefore want to write my own code to do the plotting. The pseudocode below should hopefully explain what I'm trying to do:

```
struct OHLCV
{
   //fields
   date  dt_;
   float op_;
   float hi_;
   float lo_;
   float cl_;
   ulong vol;
}

using OHLCVData = List<OHLCV>

class Plotter
{
    Plotter(OHLCVData data):m_data(data)
    {
    }

    public void plot(date startdate, date enddate)
    {
        // actually render to a control
    }

    private OHLCVData m_data;
}
```

My question is: How would I write the `plot()` function, and is there a preferred control (e.g.Canvas) that I should be "writing" to?

Comment: It's a broad question. I myself ended up with using GDI (winforms) in wpf application, rendering content into bitmap and then displaying that bitmap as `Image`. Performance of wpf when handling big number of visuals is not pretty, but it could be a good start: big `Canvas` (to position) inside `ViewBox` (to scale), and then just add [geometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx) to it.

Comment: Why do you need library that can plot only one type of chart?

Comment: @A191919: It's a utility application I am writing for my own use. I need a barebones library which just displays OHLC. Once I understand how trhe plots are being done for the (x,y) datasets, I will implement my own custom graphing, which I'm currently having to do by hand (tedious).